# Xamarin.forms CarouselView ItemsSource error System.MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, carousel, xamarin.forms, methodaccessexception

**System.MethodAccessException** has been thrown.

[This exception is always thrown for CarouselView ItemsSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt9sT.png)

Though the example from https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/ is working fine. Same implementation in different solution throws this above error always.

Comment: I've the same exception... you didn't find the solution by any chance?